# Bijections of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $c^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$ be the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients, where $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ are partitions. We know that $c^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}= c^{\lambda}_{\nu\mu}$. Up to now, what are the bijections we known to prove this equality?

Comment: I found two papers that might be helpful: https://doi.org/10.1137/17M1162834, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1773572.

Comment: Do you know how to download the first one ? I can not do this.

Comment: Sci-Hub helps with the first one. Also, there is a [preprint](http://www.mat.uc.pt/preprints/ps/p1755.pdf). Moreover, see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05037v1) (not the same paper).

Comment: thank you so much Darij!